# Rails 6 - after moving to import maps stimulus controllers don't load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs, import-maps

I have problems with updating to rails 7.x so first I try to update js related items. After install Stimulus when I try to load page I have:

```
Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production.
Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( controllers/hello_controller.js )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server
```

Of course I can add this file to precompile but here I have multiple controllers. The same issue is with load nested files with custom or vendor js code.

The error is weird because Stimulus should automatically upload all files from controllers. I guess  the issue might be with bundling files but I'm not sure.

Could you help me, please? :)

I tried to find solution but no solutions work.

**EDITED**
Updating sprockets to 4.x resolve the issue - [Upgrade Guide](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/main/UPGRADING.md#guide-to-upgrading-from-sprockets-3x-to-4x)

Comment: just add `//= link_tree ../../javascript .js` to `app/assets/config/manifest.js`

Comment: @Alex - I have this line on my manifest.js but nothing happens

Comment: Updated sprockets resolved the problem. Thanks!