# Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiledError with Rails 7 and importmap

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, import-maps

I upgraded from Rails 6 to 7 and want to setup importmap.

I am receiving `Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiledError`

```
Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production.
Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( controllers/hello_controller.js )` 
to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server
```

It know that it is not needed to precompile this file - I am wondering how should precompiling be turned off for JS files which are loaded via importmap?

My importmap.rb is same as a fresh install one:

```
pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75222482/rails-6-after-moving-to-import-maps-stimulus-controllers-dont-load%60) with some comments which let me figure out my issues as well.

Updating sprockets to 4.x resolve the issue - [upgrade guide](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/main/UPGRADING.md#guide-to-upgrading-from-sprockets-3x-to-4x)